# What do these mean pdv . vdp . d(pv)?

Tags: calculus

I am a bit new to calculus and if we have two variables p and v
$$pdv \ vdp \ d(pv)$$
what will the above quantities representmean ?

Comment: This is actually taken  thermodynamics but doassociate with anything.

Comment: In general what will these try to express?

Comment: This is what I mean:

Comment: just the way ds/dt expesses derivative of s with respect to t sdt tds or d(ts) represent?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles. After reading your title, users have no idea what the question is about, it's useless.

Comment: edited it is it ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it as the relation of the changes between two quantities as we put some 'perturbation' into the system. It is more transparent for finite changes:

$$ \Delta (PV) = V \Delta P + P \Delta V + \Delta P \Delta V$$

Now, suppose we make the magnitude of changes very small $ \Delta P , \Delta V \to (0,0)$ then:

$$ d(PV) = V dP + P dV$$

This is useful for relating the 'change' in thermodynamic variables.

---

### Illustration

Suppose we are dealing with an ideal gas and $PV= nRT$ , assuming constant moles :

$$ nR dT = V dP + PdV$$

Suppose we have a reversible isothermal process, then $ dT = 0$,

$$ V dP = - P dV$$

Or,

$$ \frac{-V}{P} = \frac{dV}{dP}$$

Since volume is always greater than zero and pressure is greater than zero, it is easy to see as we increase the volume $ \frac{-V}{P}$ becomes more negative, so the decrease in volume as we increase pressure more and more is much greater. Indeed, we have found the **partial derivative** of volume with pressure at constant temperature:

$$ \frac{-V}{P} = (\frac{\partial V}{\partial P})_T$$

tl;dr: the relation between 'small changes' in a system, helps us understand how the system behaves to be given 'small disturbances'. eg: I give a small disturbance in pressure, then how does my volume change if the process is reversible isothermal?

Edit: Oops! flipped the fraction by accident.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy#Definintion r this is beccming thermodynamics but what is "work required to achieve its pressure and volume" as I gave in the link?

Comment: That's a completely different question, you should ask another question if you want an answer to that. However, I think there is enough answers about enthalpy on physics stackexchange.

Comment: A one line something?

Comment: Not everything can be made into a one-line explanation, you need to work yourself up to that point of it rather than trying to jump to it. There is a good course on thermodynamics on youtube by mit ocw, it's done by a professor named bowendi, the enthalpy comes around lecture 6 iirc

Comment: The units for your equation don't work out.