# What will this integral solve to mainly?

Tags: calculus

<strike>What will the following integral give for variable x and y :
$$\int d(xy)$$
$$\int xyd(xy)$$
This is a followup on [What do these mean pdv . vdp . d(pv)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3939608/what-do-these-mean-pdv-vdp-dpv).</strike>

I posted this by mistake.
Just realized its like asking
$$\int udu$$

Comment: $xy + C$, and $\frac{x^2y^2}{2} + C$, respectively. What is so special about this?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int d(xy) = xy + C$$
$$\int xyd(xy) = \frac{x^2y^2}{2} + C$$

You might be confused because you see two variables instead of one, but you may notice that this is nothing new by putting $t=xy$ to get the following integrals:
$$\int dt \text{ and } \int t dt$$

Comment: Will you remove your answer I just realized I posted by mistake.

Comment: I made a mis d interpretationr.

Comment: You could completely delete it instead of using strike.

Comment: Your answer is preventing deletion cannot delete answered questions d.